# Project Euler #3 C My program displays the correct output for 13195. But it does not display anything for 600851475143

Tags: c, project

When n=13195, the program displays the correct output i.e. 29. But for the following code, the program does not display anything. Please help me fix the bug. Thank you.

```
         unsigned long long int n=600851475143;
         unsigned long long int c=0;
         unsigned long long int max=2;
        for(unsigned long long int i=2;i<=n;i++){
                if(n%i==0){
                        c=0;
                        for(unsigned long long int j=2;j<=i;j++){
                                if(i%j==0){
                                        c=c+1;
                                }
                        }
                                if(c==1){
                                        if(i>max){
                                                max=i;
                                        }
                                }

                }
        }
        printf("Largest prime factor=%d\n",max);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's not just taking forever to finish? Project Euler questions tend to not be quick to calculate.

Comment: You can't solve Project Euler problems with naive code like this: for starters you are checking all the even divisors (a simple check of divisibility by 2 will do that), and over the whole range (not just up to the square root). I suggest you research (or develop) a more efficient algorithm. You are also using `%d` to output a 64-bit value.

Comment: I'd suggest you let this code run for a day or two on a computer with a powerful processor and see what happens. Look at your code and examine what it will do if n is a prime number near six trillion. If you compile without optimisation (which will make little difference here), check what i is after running for an hour.

Comment: Your algorithm is interesting. For every factor d of n, you calculate the smallest factor of d. And then you take the largest one of those. Do you have a proof that this is the largest prime factor of n? (Well it is, but do you have a proof?)